# PHP excel download, zero bytes error

Tags: mysql, apache, joomla

My php excel download program is working well on server about 3 months, and then server down for a while.And then I can't download excel and show zero bytes. What will be the problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Permissions get removed? Not much to go on to come to a solution.

Comment: I am getting no errors.